# Laravel - page view spitting out raw laravel code

Tags: laravel

Unsure why my page is spitting out raw code.  All looks and works perfectly on my MAMP server, however I upload to live and it goes pear shaped.

At a glance, has anyone seen anything like this before?  As you can see, I'm not getting any actual errors.

[image]

Comment: If your view file is named correctly and other views are rendering fine, we would need to see your view code to see what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure you are naming your view file correctly. "view.blade.php" You need to have it named correctly to use the blade templating. Otherwise the templating stuff will output to the browser like that.

Example ... the home.php file that comes with the laravel install. That would need to be renamed to home.blade.php to use things like: @if @endif and {{ URL::asset() }}

Comment: Yes, all fine.  All other views are displaying correctly.

Comment: And you have the view named correctly? "view.blade.php"